# looking for help with Flash sound to play on an iPad

Tags: flash, ipad, audio

I hope you might be willing to help me.  Years ago, when I was designing a game site, it was recommended to me to do what you pretty much suggested in your answer to a question about Flash sound: put my sound effects as Flash elements.  This works great on every platform except the iPad.

Do you have any idea what I should do?

I'd really appreciate your help and you sound like a helpful person.  Some people here can be kind of mean.  I'm not a programmer by training, just self taught.

Comment: Additional note: I am new here and actually I find this site very difficult to figure out, so if the moderator wouldn't mind, please don't close or delete this (at least not for a couple of days) until I figure out how to utilize this site.

Comment: Whom are you addressing? This entire site? Anyways, have you considered playing them as media files, with HTML5 syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The iPad doesn't support Flash.

If you're talking about modifying your game site, you're going to have to use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag to enable sound (and the rest of the HTML5 spec to port your game from Flash).

If you're talking about porting the games on your site to iPad applications, you're going to have to learn how to program in Objective-C.

Comment: Yes I know the iPad doesn't support Flash.  SO I guess I need to go back to my original MP3 files (which as I remember is what I converted to Flash).  I guess I'm asking where is a resource so I can teach myself the HTML5 code to use.

Comment: @phm Like @tilomitra said...W3Schools has good tutorials on the subject.

Comment: "going to have to learn Objective-C" - ..or use the upcoming new version of Flash (CS5) to publish your flash game as a precompiled iPad application, it might be worth adding.

Answer (score 0):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) has reference on how to use the `<audio>` tag in HTML5